Clarification of Weinberg's cosmology book eqns 5.1.44-5.1.47 for scalar perturbation
Has anyone clarified the equations in Weinberg's cosmology book for scalar perturbation for nonzero $F$ and $B$, eqns 5.1.44-5.1.47. I am not sure why there are terms with $\nabla^2 \dot{B}$ and $\nabla^2 \ddot{B}$ terms in their eqns 5.1.44 and 5.1.47 components as there should not be any scalar terms from $B$ in the diagonal as it is evident from the tensorial decomposition $$B^S{}_{ij}=(\partial_i\partial_j-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}\nabla^2)B~ ?$$


The book is available online here http://lib.ysu.am/disciplines_bk/1e79c894ea57086081172d4988a8a3ce.pdf, refer page 226

Can you please add the cited euations to your question?

$B^S_{ij}$ does have terms on the diagonal. It is just that the trace is zero. Here's an example of a $3x3$ matrix with terms on the diagonal but zero trace
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For example, if $B(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)-z^2$, then $B^{S}_{ij}$ will be propotional to the above matrix.

Yes but $3\delta p$ is trace. So $B$ shouldn't be there. Anyway anyone have tried workout on the calculations to get the same results?

@Shiv Yeah but if you actually read the text then Weinberg says those two equations come from the $00$ component of the Einstein equations and the $ij$ part (ie, part proportional to $\delta_{ij}$). He's not taking a trace. Also the trace of the perturbed stress energy tensor would be $-\delta \rho + 3 \delta p$, not $\delta \rho +3 \delta p$. I think you're jumping to conclusions. Also this statement in your question is incorrect: "there should not be any scalar terms from  in the diagonal."

@Shiv I think you can partly track the 3 back to the fact that Weinberg is starting a form of Einstein's equations that involves the trace of the stress energy tensor, namely $R_{\mu\nu}=8\pi G(T_{\mu\nu} - T^\lambda_\lambda g_{\mu\nu})$. So there is a trace in there but you aren't tracing over the free $ij$ indices of Einstein's equations, which is what would cause the $B$ terms to cancel. Obviously you have to do all the algebra and $p$ appears in $T_{ij}$ as well, but that's a source of "extra $p$'s" to be aware of.

I actually couldn't get that eqns especially the terms with $\nabla^2\dot{B}$ and the $\nabla^2\ddot{B}$. That's why asking the question. Somehow he has used Bardeen potentials $\psi=(\partial_i\partial_j-\frac{1}{3}\nabla^2)B$ without mentioning it.

@Shiv You're unlikely to get someone willing to go through a calculation this complicated just to find an error you made. I have done this calculation a long time ago but there are a lot of details to get right. As unsolicited advice, you are more likely to get a response if you can isolate your issue into a few steps that are relatively easy to check. You did try to do that in this question by giving a general argument that terms with $B$ cannot appear because a trace over the free indices of Einstein's equations would cancel these terms. (...)

(...) All I'm saying is that a trace over the free indices was not taken, so that argument can't be correct, so if you're trying to debug the error then that is not the place to look. I'm also pointing out that the $T^\mu_\mu$ term can give you terms you normally wouldn't expect, including (I suspect) the coefficient $3$ in $3 \delta p$. A suggestion would be to set all the terms in the metric perturbation to zero instead of $B^S_{ij}$, and calculate each of the pieces of the Einstein equations. (Like $R_{ij}$). Then see at what step the $B$ terms cancel -- there's probably a mistake there.

However, "check my work" type questions are off topic, so try to reformulate any new question in a way that is conceptual if you can. The current question does have a conceptual question -- how can $B$ appear if a trace over the free indices will cause $B$ terms to cancel -- and the answer to that question is that the free indices are not being traced over.

One other piece of advice is to learn how to use a computerized tensor algebra package, like xAct for Mathematica. Using this kind of tool can really help with this kind of calculation, which require a lot of tedious but straightforward algebraic manipulations.

Another idea would be to work using flat space instead of FLRW as a background. That will make $a=1$ and $H=0$. That might simplify the calculation, and you should find the $\nabla^2 \ddot{B}$ term is there. (But the $H \nabla^2 \dot{B}$ term will vanish). If you can see how $B$ appears there, it should be easier to generalize to FLRW.

Thank you for your comments @Andrew, I got the equation only after using the terms in Bardeen potentials, $A\rightarrow A+\frac{1}{3}\nabla^2B$ but nowhere in the book mentioned about it.  When we do calculations (I am talking about $\delta\rho$ and $\delta p$ which is somehow contained in eqn 5.1.47) a straightforward answer we will get is without $\nabla^2\dot{B}$ and $\nabla^2\ddot{B}$ where I am thinking these terms in eqn 5.1.47 came from the Bardeen potentials.(...)

(...) But if so in other eqns (say for $0i$ and $jk, j\neq k$ components) it seems he is not using the same relation for $A$ that I used to arrive at eqn 5.1.47. That is why I am very doubtful....Can you please try to recall if you do the same?
